# Changing zoom level of google map with user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm attempting to change the zoom level of my google map based on user input.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;

    function initMap() {    
    var uluru = {lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194};    
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {    
    zoom: 10,    

       // standard google map javascript

    } //end of initMap() 


    $('#id_zoomlevel').on('change', function() {
       var zoomlevel = $('#id_zoomlevel :selected').attr('value');
       map.setZoom(zoomlevel);
    });

</script>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
(index):679 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setZoom' of undefined
```

How do I pass the now set map variable into to 'on change' function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `map` is both a local variable to your `initMap` method, and a  global variable. When you do `var map` inside your `initMap` method you are instead creating a new `map` variable which belongs to your `initMap` method, and not changing the outside global variable `map`. Thus, it is similar to this:

```js
var b;
function a() {
  var b = "foo"; // creates a new `b` variable within `a` (and thus nott modifying the outer `b` variable)
}
a();
console.log(b); // cannot access `b` outside of `a` (similar to `initMap`)
```

but if you remove `var` from within your inner method, you will instead change the global variable (and not create a new local variable):

```js
var b;
function a() {
  b = "foo";
}
a();
console.log(b); // cannot access `b` outside of `a` (similar to `initMap`)
```

Thus, your code should something like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map; // declare as global

    function initMap() {    
    var uluru = {lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194}; 
    //\/ --- initialize the global `map` variable (don't create a new local map variable)   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {    
    zoom: 10,    

       // standard google map javascript

    } //end of initMap() 


    $('#id_zoomlevel').on('change', function() {
       var zoomlevel = $('#id\_zoomlevel :selected').attr('value');
       map.setZoom(zoomlevel);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring new `map` variable in `initMap()` function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;

    function initMap() {    
    var uluru = {lat: 37.7749, lng: -122.4194};    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {    
    zoom: 10,    
    . . . . . . standard google map javascript .....


    $('#id_zoomlevel').on('change', function() {
       var zoomlevel = $('#id\_zoomlevel :selected').attr('value');
       map.setZoom(zoomlevel);
    });

</script>
```

use global map variable instead of local one